# Laravel post route controller method not getting called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm building an app in Laravel and I already had my user registration working fine, I now want to modify how the registration works so I modified my route to call a different method.

Originally the route was defined like so:

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

And this worked fine. I then changed it to:

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@someOtherMethod');
```

This method is defined as follows:

```
public function someOtherMethod(Request $request)
{
    die('If the method is called you should see this');
}
```

**However**, it doesn't get called (the message doesn't show). Instead it redirects me to the root of the site.

Note that I have a cache-busting script on my server that I run every time I have weird issues like this which runs the following commands:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
service php5-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

I also run the page in an incognito/private window every time I make a change.

Now for the interesting part; I tried undoing the changes I made so that it calls `postRegister` again, I fully expected this to make it revert to the default behaviour but it still redirects me to the root of the site! So now I don't even have a registration page that functions at all.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance for your help.

***Edit:***

Here's my full **`routes.php`**:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    /** Public routes **/
    Route::get('',                              'HomepageController@index');
    Route::get('/',                             'HomepageController@index');
    Route::get('terms', function() {
        return view('terms');
    });
    Route::get('privacy', function() {
        return view('privacy');
    });

    /** Public auth routes **/
    Route::get('register',                      'RegistrationController@index');
    Route::post('register',                     'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('login', function() {
        return view('auth.login');
    });
    Route::post('login',                        'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('logout',                        'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
    Route::get('dashboard/login', function() {
        return view('admin.login');
    });
    Route::post('dashboard/login',              'AdminAuth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('dashboard/logout',              'AdminAuth\AuthController@getLogout');

    /** Admin routes **/
    Route::get('dashboard', [
      'middleware' => 'admin',
      'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index'
    ]);
    Route::get('dashboard/users', [
      'middleware' => 'admin',
      'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@showUsers'
    ]);
    Route::get('dashboard/search', [
        'middleware' => 'admin',
        'as' =>   'adminSearch',
        'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@query'
    ]);

    /** Admin auth routes **/
    Route::get('dashboard/staff/create', [
        'middleware' => 'admin',
        function () {
            return view('admin.register');
        }
    ]);
    Route::post('dashboard/staff/create', [
        'middleware' => 'admin',
        'uses' => 'AdminAuth\AuthController@postRegister'
    ]);

    /** Controllers **/
    Route::controllers([
        'password' =>                           'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Hit your logout url once and try again?

Comment: Yep, I do that every time too. Besides, as I mentioned I open a new incognito/private window every time I attempt this, so being logged in shouldn't even be an issue.

Comment: Where did you place this route? outside of the `web` middleware. Right?

Comment: @Denis To what? At the moment it's set to `{{ url('/register') }}` which is what the route is pointing to.

Comment: @JilsonThomas No, inside. Is that my issue? It was working before though... or was that just a happy glitch that made it work before?

Comment: Check if you are placed the Route not in any middleware that required auth check. I'm just assuming this might be the case. Try placing it outside. Edit: Nope, I'm wrong. It should be inside the web middleware.

Comment: Can you post your whole `routes.php` file?

Comment: @JilsonThomas check the edit... it's a bit of a mess, I know. Also I tried putting the route in question on the outside of the group as you mentioned, all that did was make it redirect to the same page, rather than the home page.

Comment: note that I have some odd middleware stuff going on with the admin routes, I originally tried having these in a separate group but that didn't work. this was a different issue, though. having the routes as they are solved that (separate) issue.

Comment: Are you using default system traits for register? (the ones that comes with the package)

Comment: @Bartu I'm not using another third party package for Auth, if that's what you're saying.

Comment: Try to call method from RegisterController@postRegister

Comment: I believe that's worked! Thanks! Let me just test it a bit further before I get too excited though...

Comment: Yep that was the trick. So I'm guessing the problem is that you can't call a custom method directly on the AuthController from a route, right? Or is it something else that's up? By the way, I still have the same method on the AuthController but I call it from the RegisterController instead, as you suggested. Anyway, if you make that into an answer I'll accept it, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you remeber about `$this->middleware` in the `AuthController`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you config/auth.php is calling proper Auth guard. Also redirectsTo is by default set to '/' which is route of site. What is in your middleware? the default RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware has by default entry to point to root of the site. Only these 3 scenarios possibly acting other than expected.